# Suggestion on Turtlebot workstation install

Tags: ros, turtlebot, workstation, rosinstall, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a cryptic error message installing the turtlebot workstation:

"Whoa  -----  missing Hg  -----"

This was fixed by

sudo apt-get install mercurial

Afterward  the rossinstall worked up until the PCL perceptions checkout failed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11382/suggestion-on-turtlebot-workstation-install/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2011-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-03**:
Also what instructions are you following?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-09-30**:
Could you provide a traceback for the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated the solution is to install mercurial.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0